# how to create nested carousel with angular ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

i was suppose to create a nested carousel using ng-repeat but the child carousel does'nt work properly.. 
i can't set first item of the carousel to be active

```
 <div data-wrap="false" data-interval="false" class="carousel col-xs-12" id="Carousel" style="padding:0px">
                  <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="item  "  ng-class="{'active':  !$index}" ng-repeat="question in questions | filter:{visible: true}"  ng-if="$index< questions.questionCount">
                      <div class="row"  style="background-color:#00A693; color:#fff; font-size:20px; padding:20px; border-radius:5px; margin-right:-15px">
                        <div class="col-md-12" >
                          <p>Question: {{$index+1}} / {{questions.questionCount }} &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <spanclass="pull-center">Marks:&nbsp;<span ng-bind="question.mark"></span></span><span class="pull-right"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>:<span class="hidden-xxs"></span> <span class="time-duration"><strong></strong> <small style="color:#fff">Minutes</small></span> </span> </p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div style="float:left; width:100%;">
                        <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10 col-xs-offset-0 col-xs-12">
                          <h3 class="question" style="font-size:18px; background-color:#CCCCCC; border-radius:10px; padding:40px" >
                            <p  style="color:#000000" mathjax-bind="question.question"></p>
                          </h3>


                <div ng-if="question.sub_question==1">  


                  <div class="carousel" id="carousel1" data-wrap="false" data-interval="false">
                    <div class="carousel-inner">


                      <div class="item"  ng-repeat="quests in question.sub_question_list" ng-class="{'active': {{$index}}==0}" id="item{{$index}}">
                        <h3>Step: {{$index+1}}</h3>
                        <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10 col-xs-offset-0 col-xs-12">
                          <h3 class="sub_question" style="font-size:18px;" >
                            <p  style="color:#000000" mathjax-bind="quests.quest"></p>
                          </h3>
```

Comment: `doesn't work properly` doesn't explain a real problem

Comment: the first item of the child carousel is not getting the class name active

Comment: create a demo that replicates problem

Comment: i am trying to place a carousel inside another carousel in which the slide items of both carousel are created dynamically by ng-repeat using angularjs the problem is the inner carousel slides are not visible..